# Copying open files using scp

Tags: scp

I try to copy a MySQL data directory while MySQL is active (I know about the potential downsides to this but I can't stop MySQL because it needs to stay running).

Exporting / importing a dump is not what I want because I would like to investigate some details inside the .frm and .idb files. Because of this I want to copy them.

I can copy most of the files but some can't be copied. The failed files are owned by the mysql group and user, therefore I did a `su mysql`. But I can't copy them because I get `Permission denied`.

To find out some more details I ran `strace -v`:

```
open("webinar_citrix_go_to_meeting_appointments.frm", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 4
fstat(4, {st_dev=makedev(253, 3), st_ino=787045, st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_nlink=1, st_uid=44897, st_gid=40898, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=16, st_size=7396, st_atime=2019/06/26-00:23:19.012875620, st_mtime=2018/04/06-11:33:23, st_ctime=2018/04/27-09:00:12.027723187}) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 0
write(7, "C0660 7396 webinar_citrix_go_to_"..., 57) = 57
```

Unfortunately I didn't see an error code that backs my theory. Is there a switch I could use to have scp ignore open files?

The output of `ls -l` for one of the failed files (all failed files have identical permissions) is `-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql`.
`id` tells me that the active user has proper group memberships:

`uid=44897(mysql) gid=10100(user) groups=10100(user),40898(mysql)`

Comment: The errors that you are getting is nothing to do with file corruption. It looks like you don't have read permission.

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l` on the failed files.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, I know it is a permission issue, the files are intact because MySQL is working just fine

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I updated the question with the Information you asked for

Comment: Trying to copy live database files to investigate a problem inside them is pointless. Really. How are you going to differentiate corruption in your copies caused by the act of copying while the file is being changed, and the existing corruption (or whatever) that you're trying to investigate?

Comment: @roaima I'll answer this once I have the copy ;-) To be serious: Because the table is only read most of the time I will take the risk. As I mentioned: I know about the downsides to this approach but I want to try it anyway because bringing down the database is not an option right now

Comment: Is it running on a snapshottable filesystem (LVM, ZFS, BTRFS, etc.)?

Comment: I would export to another db, take the other db offline, and then use its files. That way it can not be corrupted by a db write.

Comment: @roaima Good idea, unfortunately no such filesystem